# Element that could be previously clicked is now no longer clickable?

Tags: python, selenium

So I've made a program that searches through a database of accounts by putting in an account number after you've logged in. Now it works perfectly on the first loop, but when I put in the next account number I get an exception error where an element is not clickable. Now I know it's clickable because it worked fine on the first loop, what is happening?

Here is that block of code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import time
import requests
import re
import csv
from tkinter import *

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.switch_to.frame("ifrmContent")

    action = ActionChains(driver)
    Activity = action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divMenu23']")).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ActImpct = action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divMenu266']")).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ClickImpct = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divMenu266']").click()

    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    ImpctBalance = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[src*="impactingActivities"]')
    driver.switch_to.frame(ImpctBalance)
    print("\n")

    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.5)
        Row3 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tblDetails']/tbody/tr[3]")))
        print("ACTIVITY IMPACTING BALANCE, REVIEW NEEDED")
        print("\n")
    except:
        print("No Activity Impacting Balance")
        print("\n")


    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tblButtonBar2']/input")))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tblButtonBar2']/input").click()
```

I don't suspect its a frame issue because it still scrapes the information from the table it brings up. I tried adding an implicit wait and some time delays to give it time to load (although that's not a problem on the first run through) just to see if that would help, but it has not.

The error I'm getting is for the last line in the program there:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I think this is a frame issue actually, even though the CSS selector is the same for that frame for some reason it can't access the elements within that frame. Had a similar issue before, for every new pop up window the number of that frame changes, but the original still remains as well so it never says it couldn't find the frame. May be screwed here.

Comment: Include the necessary imports and driver function (not selenium driver, main function) to give a reproducible code sample.

Comment: Can you post error? and line that fail if not included on error. Also complete code cause I dont see any iteration that you said

Comment: @LazyCoder I believe I updated the question with what you need, still pretty new at this.

Comment: @Wonka I included the error and the line its occurring on.